# $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^n}{n^2}$ converge or diverge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I know that as $n \to \infty, e^n$ and $n^2 \to \infty$ giving us $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$.

I can't use L'Hospital (at least I think I can't), so this series is divergent right? Is there a 'cleaner' way of evaluating the limit, i.e., for the Test for Divergence?

Thanks!

Comment: L'Hospital CAN be used for such limits. In fact, the limit is $\infty$ and the series diverges. The taylor series of $e^x$ shows easier that the limit is $\infty$. Consider $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O(x^4)$ With the taylor series, it can easily be shown that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^x}{x^n}=\infty$$ for every positive integer $n$

Comment: Ratio test gives $a_{n+1}/a_n = e \times n^2/(n+1)^2 \to e>1$.

Comment: $e^n/n^2\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ (therefore what happens?)

Comment: As a general rule of thum, exponentials grow faster than polynomials. So each term in series diverge to $\infty$, you have no chance for the series to converge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should know that L'Hopital *can* be used to evaluate that limit.  Applying it once will leave you with *another* $\displaystyle \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ indeterminant form, so you'll have to apply it a second time (at which point the denominator is constant and the numerator is still $e^x$).  You will find that $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ cannot converge since $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty \neq 0$.

---

There are all sorts of additional ways to show this series diverges.  Fnacool in the comments mentions the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test).  Another way would be to use the [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test):

We have $\displaystyle \sqrt[n]{\frac{e^n}{n^2}} = \frac{\sqrt[n]{e^n}}{\sqrt[n]{n^2}} = \frac{e}{\sqrt[n]{n} \cdot \sqrt[n]{n}}$, which goes to $e$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ because $\sqrt[n]{n} \rightarrow 1$.

Since $\sqrt[n]{a_n} \rightarrow e > 1$, it follows that $\displaystyle \sum a_n$ does not converge.

Answer (score 2):

Since exponential functions "dominate" over all polynomials, we know by L'Hopîtal's Rule that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^n}{n^2}=\infty\text{,}$$

so the sequence diverges. Thus, the sum is divergent as well.

Answer (score 1):

The series diverges because the $n^{th}$ term goes to $\infty$, and this fact can be found out by using L'hispitale rule.